# Derivative of cross-product of two vectors with respect to vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus, cross-product

$\omega$ is a 3×1 vector and $I$ is a constant 3×3 matrix. What is the derivative respect to vector $\omega$? It would be appreciated if you could show me any references I can refer to.
$$\frac{d(\omega \times I\omega)}{\omega}=?$$

Comment: Define the vector $y=(w\times Iw)$ and calculate its differential $$\eqalign{dy &= w\times Idw + dw\times Iw \cr &= {\rm skew}(w)I\,dw - {\rm skew}(Iw)\,dw }$$ The gradient should now be obvious.

Comment: Thank you greg.

Comment: [This reformulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) may also clear things up.

Comment: You can also use tensor index notation, and the identities
$$(Av)^{i} = {A^{i}}_{j}v^{j}$$
$$(v\times w)^{i} = {\epsilon^{i}}_{jk}v^{j}w^{k}$$
$${[\operatorname{skew}(v)]^{i}}_{k} = {\epsilon^{i}}_{jk}v^{j}$$
$${\epsilon^{i}}_{jk} = -{\epsilon^{i}}_{kj}$$

Comment: $\operatorname{skew}(v)$ is a matrix costructed with the components of $v$. You can see how to construct this matrix in the link provided by jnez71.

Answer (score 0):

Add $\varepsilon$ times a basis vector and look at the terms with a single $\epsilon$. That will be the corresponding column of the derivative matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The result may be $skew(\omega)I-skew(I\omega)$ but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Have you tried expanding $(\omega +\varepsilon e_1) \times I(\omega+\varepsilon e_1)$ as I proposed?